# Extract Git URL from file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, gitlab

1/ I need to extract in a folder a specific part of url. The url is in the subfolder named ".git" and I use the command:

```
git remote get-url --all origin
```

url look like this:

```
- git@servername:do-amont/production/ei2/nova/migration-devfactory.git
- ssh://servername.domain.com:30272/do-amont/production/ei2/nova/migration-devfactory.git
- https: //gitlab-review-dev-jxuor3.openshift-intra-dev.domain. com/do-amont/production/ei2/nova/migration-devfactory.git
```

the part I need is

```
do-amont/production/ei2/nova/migration-devfactory.git
```

After that I need to put the extracting url on this command

```
git remote set-url --add origin ssh://git@l203ei3007.domain.com:30272/do-amont/production/ei2/nova/migration-devfactory.git
```

I need to automatise these step on powershell

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your post currently does not contain any question - what have you tried so far, how does it fail and what is it that you need help with?

Comment: Hello Mathias. My question was "How to automatise these step with a script powershell"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the URL from the git config for a specified remote via the `git config` git command-line command, as long as you run it from within the directory with the `.git` folder.

So you could do something like this (assumes the part of the URL you want to keep is always after a colon):

```
$GitURL = (git config remote.origin.url).split(':')[1]

git remote set-url --add origin "ssh://git@l203ei3007.domain.com:30272/$GitURL"
```

Comment: Thank you Mark I try to put this on my script to test it

Comment: Hello Mark thank you it work with url begin with "git@" but I have problem with url begin "ssh://" or "https://" because they are 2 colons in the url. How to start with the 2nd colon please??? thank you again